# Finding CRD Number for Brokerage

Tags: brokerage, regulation

In order to file a complaint with FINRA, there's some identification numbers they ask for.  They ask for "SEC#" and/or "CRD#".  CRD stands for `Central Registration Depository`. According to a rep at FINRA, if an entity does brokerage transactions, they must have one or more of these numbers.

So, for example, you might have a web site address like `shareowneronline.com`, and they might call themselves `Equinity`, but neither of those gets any "hits" when searched for at https://brokercheck.finra.org/

For the sake of this question, let's presume the obvious answer "ask them", has just generated evasive responses, so another approach may need to be employed.

My working theory is that the company being searched for in `brokercheck` is not itself the actual broker.  Instead, they employ a sub-company that does the actual brokerage tasks.  It would be this sub-company that would need to be identified and placed into the search in order to uncover the `CRD Number`.

Is there a place to find out what the company hierarchy would be so that the actual brokerage company could be identified?